# Last member of each element of an id list of indices in relational dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, relational-database

Suppose I have two datasets in python: households and people (individuals). A key or id (int64) connects a household with one or more individuals. I want to create a binary variable called "last_member" that takes a value of 0 if there are more individuals in the same household, and 1 if this individual is the last member of the household.

A trivial example would be the following:

```
last_member id ...
0           1  ...
0           1  ...
1           1  ...
1           2  ...
0           3  ...
1           3  ...
...
```

I can get the number of unique ids from the households dataset or from the individual's dataset itself.

I get a feeling that either [numpy's where function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), or [pandas' aggregate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) are strong candidates to find such a solution. Still, I can't wrap my head around an **efficient** solution that does not involve, let's say, looping over the list of indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I coded a function that runs efficiently and solves the problem. The idea is to create the variable "last_member" full of zeros. This variable lets us compute the number of members per id using [pandas' groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). Then we compute the cumulative sum (minus 1, because of python's indexing) to find the indices where we would like to change the values of the "last_member" variable to 1.

```
def create_last_member_variable(data):
    """ Creates a last_member variable based on the index of id variable.
    """
    data["last_member"] = 0
    n_members = data.groupby(["id"]).count()["last_member"]
    row_idx = np.cumsum(n_members) - 1 
    data.loc[row_idx, "last_member"] = 1

    return data
```